# Cycle radio buttons

Tags: jquery, css, radio-button, cycle

I would like to cycle through 3 radio buttons (as seen below) with a 5 second delay between each selection change. What is the best way to approach this?
The reason I require this is because I am using these radio buttons as my navigation for a slideshow.

```
  <input type="radio" name="myImages" id="cover1" checked />
                <input type="radio" name="myImages" id="cover2" />
                <input type="radio" name="myImages" id="cover3" />
```

Any help would be much appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a basic example of how to do what you asked with jQuery:

```
$(function(){
  var id = 1;
  window.setInterval(function(){
    $( "#cover" + id ).prop( "checked", true );

    if (id == 3) {
        id = 1;
    }
    else {
        id++;
    }
}, 5000);
})
```